# How do open widget when clicked label

Tags: python

In my code, i have 2 widget and 1 mainwindow. when my program starting, Main window's central widget is "login". I want that when i click registration(login widget's label),reg widget open. I do it, but then i click login(register's widget's label) the same think dont happening. Sorry for bad english.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.login = login()
        self.reg = reg()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.login)
        self.setWindowTitle("Main")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.login.label_4.mousePressEvent = self.click
        self.show()

    def click(self,event):

        if event:
            self.setCentralWidget(self.reg)
            self.reg.label_4.mousePressEvent = self.click_2

    def click_2(self,event):

        if event:
            self.setCentralWidget(self.login)
            self.login.label_4.mousePressEvent = self.click
```

---

```
class login(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.label_1 = QLabel("Login:       ")
        self.line_1 = QLineEdit()
        self.h_box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.h_box.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.h_box.addWidget(self.line_1)

        self.label_2 = QLabel("Password:")
        self.line_2 = QLineEdit()
        self.line_2.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.h_box2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.h_box2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.h_box2.addWidget(self.line_2)

        self.buton_1 = QPushButton("Login")

        self.label_4 = QLabel("Register")
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color : blue")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.v_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.v_box.addLayout(self.h_box)
        self.v_box.addLayout(self.h_box2)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.buton_1)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.label_4)

        self.setLayout(self.v_box)
```

---

```
class reg(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.label_1 = QLabel("Login:                    ")
        self.line_1 = QLineEdit()
        self.h_box1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.h_box1.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.h_box1.addWidget(self.line_1)

        self.label_2 = QLabel("Password              ")
        self.line_2 = QLineEdit()
        self.line_2.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.line_2.resize(300,300)
        self.h_box2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.h_box2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.h_box2.addWidget(self.line_2)

        self.label_3 = QLabel("Retype password:")
        self.line_3 = QLineEdit()
        self.line_3.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.h_box3 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.h_box3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.h_box3.addWidget(self.line_3)

        self.buton_1 = QPushButton("Register")
        self.label_4 = QLabel("Login")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet('color: blue')

        self.v_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.v_box.addLayout(self.h_box1)
        self.v_box.addLayout(self.h_box2)
        self.v_box.addLayout(self.h_box3)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.buton_1)
        self.v_box.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.setLayout(self.v_box)

        self.setWindowTitle("Login")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the method `setCentralWidget` delete the reference to the current widget [(doc)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget). So when you try to show it again, your Python reference `self.login` refers to something that have been deleted.

There is a workaround : assigning a `None` parent to the current central widget just before setting a new central widget (this will force the program to keep a reference):

```
self.centralWidget().setParent(None)
self.setCentralWidget(self.reg)
```

For `self.reg` maybe you will prefer to delete the form and recreate a new one if the user click again on the button register ?

Comment: Nice! this link is interesting if you wanna know more about this kind of issue within PyQt :  [PyQt. How to shoot yourself in the foot](http://enki-editor.org/2014/08/23/Pyqt_mem_mgmt.html)